# Can't get google event tracker to work with php link

Tags: php, tracking, google-analytics-api

I have a site that generates an "apply" link through php. I need to have it so that the google event tracker code is listed immediately after the a href="www.link.com" url, so that it works properly... the tracking code is installed on the site, but I think that its placement on the page is what's causing the issue of not tracking the event on google analytics.

Google's example is right after the url like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>
```

When you visit my live site, the link generated in html is:

```
<a class="btn apply_now applybottom" target="_blank" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent',      'Apply',     'ApplyClick'," href="http://siteurl.com">Apply Now »</a>
```

The way that's done through php is this:

```
 <?php if (!isset($this->job['hide_apply']) || $this->job['hide_apply'] == 0): ?>
      <?php $onClick = "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Apply', 'ApplyClick'," ?>
    <?php if (isset($this->job['modal_style']) && $this->job['modal_style'] == 'none'): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Clean::xss($this->job['apply_url']); ?>"  onClick="<?php echo $onClick;     ?>" target="_blank"  class="btn apply_now applybottom" >Apply Now »</a>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Based off that, does anyone know of a way I can get it so that the tracker code is immediately after the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you need the event tracking code appended to the url, I don't think that's necessary for event tracking to work. With universal analytics ([analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#usingjquery) rather than the old ga.js) you could capture the click event with a simple jQuery function like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.btn.apply_now.applybottom').on('click', function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'apply', 'applyclick');
    });
});
</script>
```

Of course this will require that you include the jQuery library, and I don't know much about how jQuery and PHP interact so apologies if this isn't an option for you. Also using analytics.js doesn't mean you need to remove the old ga.js. You can simply double tag (as Justin Cutroni confirms [here](http://cutroni.com/blog/2012/10/29/universal-analytics-the-next-generation-of-google-analytics/#comments) - see comments).